# Convert Float value to two point decimal

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, precision

I need to find the way for converting the Float value in to the two point decimal.

I have a API code which is implemented already which will be returning the two Float value.

For example consider it is returning the values as follows: 293.019999504

But I need to make it as 293.01 instead of 293.019999504

As well as it should be handling 0 as 0.00

I am unable to modify the API implementation backend or DB tables.

I need to implement this in views.py where I am getting the values using the API calls.

Need a way to achieve this in pythonic way.

Comment: what is code you have written so far?

Comment: 1) Are you receiving these values as floats or as strings? 2) Why do you want 293.01 rather than 293.02?

Comment: Making it as 293.02, Value receiving is as floats

Answer (score 3):

You should do as follows:

```
a = 293.019999504
print("{0:.2f}".format(a))
>> 293.02
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to use the round function:

```
round(293.019999504,2)
Out[1]:
293.02
```

Note that it will round your number (so 293.019 will end up as 293.02), if you don't want that, you can use floor:

```
from math import floor
floor(100*293.019999504)/100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to round down, you need something like

```
    int(293.019999504 * 100) / 100.0
```

However, the correct way of dealing with accounting matters is fixed point calculations as described here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html.